# Simple Javascript slide function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm trying to make a simple 'slideshow' with images. Here is my code, put it does not work, it load the html code as normal, ignoring the 'hide' functionality: What to do?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var tot = $(".slide").length,
            current = 1

            $(".slide").not(":first").hide()

            $("#next").click(function () {
            if (current+1 > tot) return false

            $(".slide:visible").hide().next().show()
            current++
            })

            $("#prev").click(function () {
            if (current-1 < 1) return false

            $(".slide:visible").hide().prev().show()
                current--
            })
        })​
    </script>

    <div id="slide_container">  
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Step 1 explained</p>
                <img src="images/android.png" border="none"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Step 2 Explained</p>
                <img src="images/apple.png" border="none"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Step 3 explained</p>
                <img src="images/windows.png" border="none"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="prev">Prev</button>
                <button id="next">Next</button> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you missed the `;`-s from the script

Comment: Thanks, but still cannot get it to work, had commas(;) all over the place after every break, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I've reformatted your code and added a few semi-colons`;` for clarity and I've also changed the indexing of the current and total, and all seems to work okay I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NL7EJ/) using the below JavaScript, and all seems to work fine. Give this a go

```
$(function()
{
    var total = $(".slide").length;
    var current = 0

    $(".slide").not(":first").hide()

    $("#next").click(function ()
    {
        if (current + 1 >= total)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $(".slide:visible").hide().next().show();
        current++
    })

    $("#prev").click(function ()
    {
        if (current <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $(".slide:visible").hide().prev().show();
        current--;
    });
})​
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used it as is, still does not work...I do have JS enabled...

Comment: The original code I posted also works in JSFiddle, with all its flaws..How's that?

Comment: I'm starting to get the impression there's an error on your page, but this isn't the cause. :) Try opening your page in FireFox and viewing the console in Firebug, should give you an error log.

Comment: I tried it but Firebug does not show me any problems. I really tried making this work in different pages, but it just does not work... Is this Jquery or regular Javascript? I do however have a jquery library included for something else in my web page

Comment: The `$` is a jQuery function, and is the primary interaction with the jQuery library. :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have the Jquery reference added before the script block you provided here. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, I do. I use this - <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>